# how write to cell that spans multiple columns using excelJS?

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

can I create an excel cell which spans multiple columns using excelJS?

I tried getCell with a cell range.  But the value was set in only the first column.

```
function colSpamDemo( )
{
  let wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  let ws = wb.addWorksheet('Export');

  ws.getCell('A1:C1').value = 'This price list supercedes all prior price lists.';
  ws.getCell('A1:C1').alignment = { horizontal:'center'} ;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a [merged cell](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs#merged-cells), which sounds like what you are looking for.

```
function colSpamDemo( )
{
  let wb = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  let ws = wb.addWorksheet('Export');

  ws.mergeCells('A1:C1');
  ws.getCell('A1').value = 'This price list supercedes all prior price lists.';
  ws.getCell('A1').alignment = { horizontal:'center'} ;
}
```